# how to get UUID in j2me?

Tags: java-me, mobile, uuid, imei

in java we can get UUID from class ie UUID.randomUUID().toString()

how to get UUID in j2me ?

is there any function or class which provides it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A unique identifier for cell phone other than IMEI or IMSI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838964/an-unique-identifier-for-cell-phone-other-than-imei-or-imsi) - answer is here.