# How to generate UUID in J2ME?

Tags: java-me, uuid

I want to generate UUID in J2ME. but I can't get it. please help me.

I found everywhere..

```
UUID uuid= UUID.randomUUID();

System.out.println("UUID : " + uuid);
```

but this is not working in my NetBeans. It gives an error to me that create class randomUUID(), because it is a java class. so.. :(

In my Netbeans SDK 3.5 is there.

and I even dont want to use

```
LocalDevice.getLocalDevice().getBluetoothAddress()
```

because I used it but it is restricted to the device which have Bluetooth. Application can not run if it doesnt have bluetooth.so pls if you find another way then please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get UUID in j2me?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839436/how-to-get-uuid-in-j2me)