# How to uniquely identify a downloaded Java ME app

Tags: java-me, imei

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A unique identifier for cell phone other than IMEI or IMSI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838964/a-unique-identifier-for-cell-phone-other-than-imei-or-imsi)

I have the following problem:
I want to offer a Java ME app for download, which can obviously be installed on a mobile phone (different manufacturers and models) and will afterwards - when used - communicate with a web server. During this communication I need to uniquely identify the app (i.e. the phone/user) but preferably without bothering the user to enter a username/password or something.

My first attempt was too use the phone's IMEI, but it's a pain in the a** to retrieve the IMEI from a phone using JavaME and for some phones it does not seem to be possible at all. At least I couldn't find a way to guarantee that the app will transmit a correct IMEI for every phone. Please, anyone correct me if I'm wrong.

Second idea was too encode an ID into the app before it is downloaded. Is there a standard/preferred way to do this (besides adding the ID to the .jad file)? Any hints would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

How about using the `System.currentTimeMillis()` at the first time the user fires up the MIDlet?  The chances of this being identical for two users are slim-to-none ;)